# How to seach column for all text matches in column A and sum all of the corrosponding values in column B Excel

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I'm sure this is possible, but I've been trying various ways for the past 2 hours and can't find the solution.

I need to find all the instances of a text name in column A, lookup all the numerical results in column B and sum them together.

I thought =Arr`ayFormula(sum(lookup(F2,$A$2:$B$1000)))` would do the trick, but it's only picking up the last value on the last mention and not all the values of all the mentions.

I've attached a spreadsheet to show the data I'm looking at.

[image]

Comment: `=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,F2)`.

Comment: Thanks so much! How do I not know this function!!!!! I've solved with =SUMIFS(B2:B3115,A2:A3115,F2)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the reference from BigBen to check out Sumifs. Using this command, the following works a treat:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B3115,A2:A3115,F2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:B; "select A,sum(B) where A is not null group by A label sum(B)''")
```